# Navbar logic - assigning a class to a button when navigating to a user route except for a specific user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a navbar with buttons that gain an 'activeTab' class if the browser route meets specific criteria for each button. For one of the buttons which takes a user to their profile, the activeTab class is added to the button when the browser is at the user page for the logged in user - code shown below:

```
className={
  location.pathname === "/userDetails" ||
  location.pathname === `/users/${userInfo.username}`
    ? "activeTab"
    : null
}
```

The above works well. What is not working is trying to implement logic which makes another button the activeTab when the browser navigates to a user page which is NOT the logged in user. The logic I have in mind is something like this:

```
className={
  location.pathname === "/exploreUsers" ||
  location.pathname === `/users/${!userInfo.username}`
    ? "activeTab"
    : null
  }
```

or this:

```
className={
  location.pathname === "/exploreUsers" ||
  location.pathname === `/users/${*}`
    ? "activeTab"
    : null
}
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions on the implementation here?

Comment: We need a bit more context. Please edit your post to include a more complete and comprehensive code example. See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue lies with your `!userInfo.username` logic.  That is returning a false or true value, and is not doing any comparison to the logged in user. So what that template literal is evaluating to is:

```
"users/false"
```

Instead, I think you could change the logic to do a comparison of the current user vs. the pathname.  This will involve manipulating the pathname string to only look at the username portion.

ex:

```
className = {
  location.pathname === "/exploreUsers" ||
  location.pathname.split('/')[2] !== userInfo.username
    ? "activeTab"
    : null
}
```

I'm splitting the pathname string on the `/` character, which will return an array of strings that in between the slashes.

ex:

```
"/users/bobby".split('/')  // => ['', 'users', 'bobby']
```

Then I call the 2nd index of that array (the 3rd value), which will be the username `bobby`.  From there I test that the current user does not equal the pathname user, and add the class accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful explanation! It worked to fix my problem. I hadn't arrived to the conclusion that the route was evaluating to /false, as you mentioned. And your suggested implementation worked well once I added (location.pathname.split('/')[2] !== userInfo.username && location.pathname.split("/")[1] === "users").